# Bootstrap modal closes when focus on textarea

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal. The problem is when I try to focus on the textarea the modal disappears.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Secret #<?php echo $counter; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button name="comment" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting it to have?

Comment: Could StackOverflow force downvoters trolls to say WHY they downvote?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am expecting to prevent the closing when focus on that input. It is natural to allow the user to focus the input box for typing ~

Comment: So you want to have a modal visible while a user is typing in an `input` which is outside of the modal?

Comment: The modal-footer is inside the form that is inside the modal-body. I suspect an architecture default here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the input is inside the modal (comment) ~

Comment: @Hatem that's a textarea. I'll amend your question for you to save confusion.

Comment: Can't replicate your issue http://www.bootply.com/hUv2Oi2c0d

Comment: yeah, seems fine... [demo](http://www.bootply.com/so45bo7bkd)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Bootstrap, v3.3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , I have solved this by preventing triggering events for the comment box :

```
    $( ".modal form #comment" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.stopPropagation();

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I put my model on top of everything, solved for me.

```
<body>
   <form>
     <div class="modal fade" ... >
```